# javascript error is null or not an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to open a window from a php script. But when I click I get this error

Line: 389
Error: 'surgExpressBuildDefaultButton' is null or not an object

Line 389 code is as follow

```
function setupLayout(i)
{
 document.body.onselectstart = function()
 {
  if (event.srcElement.tagName.search(/input|textarea/i)) return false;
 }

 setupButtons();
 if(window.parent.opener.parent.frames[0].surgExpressBuildDefaultButton)
 {
  buttonClick(window.parent.opener.parent.frames[0].surgExpressBuildDefaultButton);
 }
 else
 {
  layout.buttons.commonButton.fixSelected();
 }

 for(i = 0; i < da.imgPlus.length; i++)
 {
  da.imgPlus[i].onclick = clickPlus;
  da.imgMinus[i].onclick = clickMinus;
 }

 for(i = 0; i < da.spnName.length; i++)
 {
  da.spnName[i].selected = 0;
  da.spnName[i].title = da.spnName[i].innerText;

  da.spnName[i].onclick = function(){selectCommonProcedure(this);}
  da.spnName[i].ondblclick = function(){addCommonProcedure(this);}

  da.spnName[i].onmouseout = function(){this.className = (this.selected ? "nSelected" : "nOut");}
  da.spnName[i].onmousedown = function(){this.className = "nDown";}
  da.spnName[i].onmouseover = da.spnName[i].onmouseup = function(){this.className = "nOver";}
 }

 da.inpSearch.onkeydown = function(){if(event.keyCode == 13) updateProcedureList();}

 da.btnSearch.onclick = da.selSpecialty.onchange = updateProcedureList;

 da.btnClose.onclick = function(){window.close();}

 da.btnAdd.disable = da.btnSave.disable = CC.Disable;
 da.btnAdd.disable(1);
 da.btnAdd.onclick = addCommonProcedure;
 da.btnSave.disable(1);
 da.btnSave.onclick = saveExpress;
}
```

what could be the problem. Any idea?

Comment: Which one of those four dozen or so lines is line 389?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without knowing *which* of those four dozen lines is line 489, but this jumped out at me:

```
function setupLayout(i)
{
 document.body.onselectstart = function()
 {
  if (event.srcElement.tagName.search(/input|textarea/i)) return false;
      ^-- here
```

You're using `event` without having declared it (at least, not in the code you quoted). On IE, that'll work because IE makes the event object a property of `window` (and unless they're shadowed by other declarations, you can access `window` properties without explicitly qualifying them), but on most other browsers the event object is an argument to the event handler function – and so that code tries to use an `undefined` value as an object reference, which triggers exactly the error message you're seeing.

The usual idiom for dealing with this discrepancy in browsers (other than using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) or [Prototype](http://prototypejs.org) that handle it for you) is this:

```
document.body.onselectstart = function(event)
{
    event = event || window.event;
    // ...
};
```

That idiom declares `event` it as an argument to the function, but then has it fall back to looking on the `window` (to support IE).